# Input field focus on safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari

I have a input field on my page that I use to scan barcodes. I autofocus the input field with `document.getElementById("barcode").focus();` it works fine on chrome/firefox, but when running the page on safari on iPhone SE the input field doesn't get focused when clicking on my alert which looks like this

```
function x() {
    if (confirm("are you sure?")) {
        alert("registered");
        document.getElementById("barcode").focus();
    }
}
```

How can I fix this? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can see this document, 
I think there is maybe not work

[MDN Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus#Focus_prevent_scroll)

you can try using `jQuery.focus()`